# No Audio Device and Wi-Fi after changes in msconfig

Tags: windows-10, dell-inspiron

I have a DELL Ispirion 17 7779 2-in-1 running on Windows 10 PRO and after a suggestion of a friend I changed one single setting in msconfig.

After the reboot both my audio and wi-fi are not working anymore (no Audio device detected). Even if I try to download and reinstall the drivers from scratch (from dell official website), or revert my msconfig setting both audio and Wi-Fi are still now working and showing as no device available.

Any idea what I should do?
Thank you

Comment: _"I changed one single setting in msconfig."_ - which was what exactly?

Comment: Number of CPU at startup, which I have already reverted to original value

Comment: Have you tried to set the startup selection to Normal startup